# dynamic content not loaded from file in AJAX code

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, servlets

Dynamic code not loaded up in the page. It loads only when I reload the program again

Tried onload event in body. It loads the content from xml file using ajax code only after closing and running it again, not in the same window

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function hi(id)
        {

            document.getElementById(id).contentEditable=true;

        }
        function hello(id,data)
        {
            document.getElementById(id).contentEditable=false;
            var changedtext=document.getElementById(id).textContent;
           // alert(changedtext)
            data.value=changedtext;
           // alert(data)
        }
     function display(i) {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this, i);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.xml", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml, i) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; 
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("home");
    document.getElementById("myid1").innerHTML =
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("topicsCovered") 
     [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("myid2").innerHTML =
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("summary")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
        </script>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1.0">
</head>
<body onload="display(0)">
    <form action="mybackend"  method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="pdata" value="I am a paragraph">
        <input type="hidden" name="divdata" value="TODO write content">
    <div id="myid1">TODO write content</div>
<input type="button" value="edit me" onclick="hi('myid1')"/>
    <input type="button" value="save" 
onclick="hello('myid1',this.form.divdata)"/><br> 
<p id="myid2">I am a paragraph</p>  
   <input type="button" value="edit me" onclick="hi('myid2')"/>
<input type="button" value="save" 
onclick="hello('myid2',this.form.pdata)"/><br> 
<br>

<input type="submit" value="save all changes in the page">
     <div id="demo"></div>
        </form>
      </body>
     </html>
```

Servlet code

```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        // processRequest(request, response);
        String divvalue=request.getParameter("pdata");
        String pvalue=request.getParameter("divdata");


        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(divvalue);
        out.println(pvalue);

        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = 
       DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        //creating a new instance of a DOM to build a DOM tree.
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        new mybackend().createXmlTree(doc,divvalue,pvalue);

        out.println("<b>Xml File Created Successfully</b>");
       // response.sendRedirect("index.html");
         response.sendRedirect("success.html");
      // new mybackend().callme(response);

      //  request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").forward(request, 
  response);

       } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(mybackend.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
 null, ex);
    }


    }


  private void createXmlTree(Document doc,String divvalue,String pvalue) 
 {
       try {
          // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported 
  yet.");
        Element root = doc.createElement("home");
        //adding a node after the last child node of the specified node.
        doc.appendChild(root);

        Element child = doc.createElement("summary");
        root.appendChild(child);

        Text text = doc.createTextNode(divvalue);
        child.appendChild(text);


        Element child1 = doc.createElement("topicsCovered");
        root.appendChild(child1);

        Text text1 = doc.createTextNode(pvalue);
        child1.appendChild(text1);



        Element child2 = doc.createElement("whowillbenefit");
        root.appendChild(child2);


        //TransformerFactory instance is used to create Transformer 
      objects.
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();

        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        // create string from xml tree
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        try {
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        } catch (TransformerException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(mybackend.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
    null, ex);
        }
        String xmlString = sw.toString();

        File file = new 
 File("C:\\Users\\csestaff\\Documents\\
 Gift\\Stigmata\\livedata\\livedata\\web 
    \\data.xml");
        BufferedWriter bw=null;
        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new 
  FileOutputStream(file)));

        bw.write(xmlString);
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(mybackend.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
 null, e);
        }

    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(mybackend.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
   null, ex);
    }



}
```

XML FILE

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <home>
 <summary>Praney is good</summary>
 <topicsCovered>Ruthra is good</topicsCovered>
 <whowillbenefit/>
 </home>
```

loads the content of the file first, when i edit it, it loads it again only after closing and opening it again, not dynamically

Comment: You can force a refresh of your application with `ctrl + F5`. Then it reloads everything including scripts. Otherwise it gets file from browser-cache. Read this https://lifehacker.com/shift-refresh-is-like-the-restart-button-for-web-sites-5574852 and https://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache/.

Answer (score 0):

To disable browser's cache when loading ajax, you can add some extra data into request URL, for example:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.xml?random=" + Date.now(), true);
```